# Using variable as an array name in Codeigniter view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, variables

I passed `$data` array to view. `$data` array is like:

```
$data = array('t0' => array('point' => 0), 't1' => array('point' => 2) .... );
```

What I am trying to do is using this array in my view as follows:

```
<?php echo $t0['point']; ?> //It works!
```

But I am doing this in a `for` loop by definition of structure. Therefore I need to pass numeric value(near '`t`' letter) as a variable.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
$count = count($data);   //if you know the count of $data
 for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $var = 't'.$i;
        echo ${$var}['point'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to send through a count in your data, so you can later run a loop, so change your `$data` array to something like:

```
$data = array('tCount' => 10, 't0' => array('point' => 0), 't1' => array('point' => 2) .... );
```

Note the addition of the `tCount` variable in the array, that should tell how many t items you are sending in the array, we'll use that in the loop below.

Now you can use a [variable variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), something like:

```
foreach ($i = 0; $i < $tCount); $i++) {
    $key = 't' . $i;
    echo($$key['point']);
}
```

Note the use of the double `$`

Comment: I am getting the error: Message: Illegal string offset 'point'.

Comment: made an edit to ensure you send a tCount to your view, otherwise there's no way of knowing how many times to loop through